# How to call two actions in same method?

Tags: axios, react-native

I have 2 actions which are :

**This is first**

*I insert person here :*

```
export const InsertOrUpdate = (person) => {

    return (dispatch) => {
        var instance = Axios.create({
            baseURL: 'url',
            // timeout: 1000,
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
        });
        instance.get("/InsertWorker", {
            params: {
                Name: person.Name,
                Surname: person.Surname,
                Duty: person.Duty,
                DateOfDay: person.Date.substring(0, person.Date.length - 9),
                Shift: person.Shift,
                WorkDayCount: person.WorkDayCount,
                Equipment: person.Equipment,
                Sicil: person.Sicil,
                Ship: person.Ship
            }
        });


    }
}
```

**This is second**

*I call workers here :*

```
export const getSignedWorkers = (collection) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        var instance = Axios.create({
            baseURL: 'url',
            // timeout: 1000,
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
        });

        instance.get('/GetWorkers', {
            params: {
                DateOfDay: collection.Tarih,
                Shift: collection.Vardiya
            }
        })
            .then((response) => response.data)
            .then(x => {
                const Signed = str3.filter(x => x.Ship != "" && x.Shift != "H");
                console.warn('signed', Signed);

                const UnSigned = str3.filter(x => x.Ship == "" || null);
                const RemoveOnHolidays = UnSigned.filter(x => x.Shift != "H");

                const OnHoliday = str3.filter(x => x.Shift == "H");

                const AllWorkers = {};
                AllWorkers.signed = Signed;
                AllWorkers.Unsigned = RemoveOnHolidays;
                AllWorkers.OnHoliday = OnHoliday;

                dispatch({ type: FETCH_SIGNED_WORKERS_SIGNED, payload: AllWorkers });

            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.warn('error', error);
            })

    }
}
```

*I call this actions here :*

```
_Insert = (person) => {
        person.Ship = this.props.gemi_Sefer_No;

        this.props.InsertOrUpdate(item);    <------- Here I call first action

        var date = new Date().getDate(); //Current Date
        var month = new Date().getMonth() + 1; //Current Month
        var year = new Date().getFullYear(); //Current Year
        var tarih = year + "/" + month + "/" + date;

        let collection = {};
        collection.Tarih = tarih;
        collection.Vardiya = this.props.vardiya == 0 ? "S" : this.props.vardiya == 1 ? "A" : this.props.vardiya == 2 ? "G" : null


        this.props.getSignedWorkers(collection);   <--- Here I call second action

    }
```

*I try to insert workers to database then call  all workers from database and use another component with redux. However, sometimes it works correctly sometimes not.*

*I mean , when I insert to database and call back again, insert worker works right however calling all workers come without worker which I insert last one. As I said, it works sometimes right. What should I do ?. Is that wrong to call two actions in same method ? if it is, what should I do ?*

Comment: None has  idea ?

Comment: Seems like you should use 'promises' to make sure your previous action finishes first.
insert(person) => {stuff}.then{ show(workers)}.
Not exactly sure how to arrange it in this code though

Comment: I couldnt handle it. I put console.log to two actions in and seems that first action finish and then it goes another action but still works wrong. I really dont understand why

Comment: Can someone help me please